# django admin page wont show

Tags: python, django

I have seen several questions relating to this topic but none work for me
I am running Django 3 and python 3 with ubuntu and using firefox browser

when i run "python3 manage.py runserver"

my homepage loads at 127.0.0.1:8000
but when I add /admin in the browser

127.0.0.1:8000/admin

it still stays at the homepage not the admin page

i notice on the running server i get

December 09, 2019 - 00:40:46
Django version 1.11.11, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
"
"and when i add /admin the following line appears"

[09/Dec/2019 00:46:05] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 3

but still i dont see the admin page

please ask and i can share

"settings.py" etc and any other information
update

my "main" folder has a urls.py file which looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
]
```

my "mysite/mysite" folder has a urls.py file that looks like:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Thanks to a comment from @chrisbyte if i comment out

```
#url(r'^', include('main.urls'))
```

Line then my admin page shows up, But then I dont get anything I have done on my "main" page.

Comment: Hello! Could you share your main urls.py please? Just to verify it is setup correctly. It needs to import `from django.contrib import admin` and have something like `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),` in your urls patterns, BEFORE you include your public urls, which looks like `url(r'^', include('your.public.urls')),`

Comment: this is the urls.py in my  "main"folder from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
]

Comment: My "mysite" app has urls.py like this  from django.conf.urls import url, include  
from django.contrib import admin  
urlpatterns = [  
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),  
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),  ]

Comment: If you could edit your original question and add the contents of the url files you mentioned, that would be incredibly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for adding this information! Are you following a tutorial or something to get setup? I am trying my best to debug based on what I am seeing. If you comment out all url patterns except `admin` and then run the application, and go to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` do you see the admin section then?

Comment: It has been some time since I have setup a django website from scratch, but I do know the admin section needs to be installed and all migration scripts run to setup the database. What database are you using with your application? Could you also share your settings.py file, or more specifically the `INSTALLED_APPS` definition? Perhaps this link could be of some help? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-and-connect-the-django-admin-interface

Comment: Hi thanks for helping, yes that worked when i commented out all patterns except admin i got the admin page :). but I am not sure what this means?. I am following "Django web development" tutorials from sentdex on youtube, maybe i should go back and see if i made a mistake ( i am also using a later version of django than in the tutorials). Thanks again for your help, i have to get some sleep now, but i will check again tommorrow thanks again for your help and hopefully this will be solved soon

Comment: Thanks to a comment from @chrisbyte if i comment out

#url(r'^', include('main.urls'))

Line then my admin page shows up, But then I dont get anything I have done on my "main" page.

Answer (score 1):

So with formatting, your urls.py looks something like this?

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin 

urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')), 
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
]
```

What happens if you put the `admin` url route before the `main.urls` route, like this?

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')), 
]
```

I believe the `admin` portion should come first so it is not overwritten by `main.urls`

Comment: Hi just to note the code you are commenting on above is not my "mysite/main" urls.py                                                                                                                        this is the urls. py in my "mysite/mysite" folder?                                                     ps: i tried swapping those two lines to put admin first but this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that due to the fact I was not working in an environment that had python 3 as its main python, it had actually downloaded an earlier version of Django. this was more confusing as my "IDLE" pointed to python 3, and when i asked for Django version In Idle it told me version 3, but when i asked for Django version in a shell in my workspace it told me the actual version was 1.

I had tried to adapt a tutorial that used "Path" syntax to my code above which did not exist in the earlier version of Django.

I followed another tutorial that was for an earlier version of django and it worked ok.

The lesson learned was to use a conda environment with the correct version of python.